# How do I display user avatar pictures in the frame of the thumbnail?

Tags: php, html, css

All uploaded images on my website have a frame around the thumbnail. I have it set up so that there is room to display the user's name, and avatar picture in the frame, with their uploaded image. Hopefully these two images give a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish 
[link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg13u.jpg)

I use this for the user names and profile pictures:

```
<?php if( $ib->user['id'] ) {?>
div class="userInfo">
<img class="avatar" width="40" height="40" src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath.$ib->user['avatar']; ?>"/>
<div class="name">
    <strong>
        <a href="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath.'user/'.$ib->user['name']; ?>"><?php echo $ib->user['name']; ?></a>
    </strong>
</div>
```

And this for the frame around the uploads

```
#imageGrid div {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 padding: 60px 10px 10px 10px;
 moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
 box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #a1a1a1;
 background-color: #dddddd;
```

I had no clue on what I should try next, so I wanted to see if I could just sort of add/combine the divs, but that won't work.

If you need more info, a better description, or more code, let me know. Thanks in advance, I'm pretty new at this, and this is the one thing I am stuck on.

Comment: Can you provide a demo with HTML and CSS that we can inspect ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put them in a container element which controls the layout of what is in it, you could use userInfo

```
<div class="userInfo">
<img class="avatar" width="40" height="40" src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath.$ib-      >user['avatar']; ?>"/>
<div class="name">
<strong>
    <a href="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath.'user/'.$ib->user['name']; ?>"><?php echo $ib->user['name']; ?></a>
</strong>
</div>
</div>

.userInfo {
width:50px;
 }

.avatar {
width:40px;
}

.name {
width:40px;
 }
```

as for #imageGrid div I would remove most of what you have in there and apply it to the specific CSS classes I have added above.

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't work. I think I just need to find the right file to put the divs in. Thanks for the help.